# How to deleselect a row from UIPickerview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

Hi I am using `picker view`, by default it is selecting the first row. I don't want this option. For example I am having "No" and "yes" options.If i give this option in pickerview "No " will be selected in pickerview (attached screenshot).I dont need this.I need first row as empty .once the user selects on "No" or "Yes" then only it need to show as a selected row. Related screenshot attached below.
How to this?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3IJT.png]

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get this one by  using `UIPickerView` then pass the first `component` of the picker view as a empty value,otherwise you can use `custom pickerview`.

```
[pickerArray addObject:@""];//first element of the picker component.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't do deselecting all the rows in uipickerview.

One thing you can do is create an additional row(eg: Select Option) in the top and default selection change to that row.
Dont forget to change in your delegate method.

Answer (score -1):

In the `viewDidLoad`   add this line

```
[picker selectRow:**selectedRow** inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

**Note:selectedRow** is the row number which you want to show as selected.

Answer (score -1):

if you need to show selection indicator only on row selection from picker view

when dragging it on xib set its behavior in right pane **uncheck** the "shows selection indicator"
and then in this method

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{       
    PickerSamples.showsSelectionIndicator=YES;       
}
```

here picker samples is my picker.....

Comment: This doesn't work from iOS 7 as indicator will always be shown from iOS 7.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me

```
[picker selectRow:-1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```