# UIPickerView don't select any row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I am implementing UIPickerView in my project. My issue is when user loads the view I don't want to select any rows. For example If I want to select any row I can use below code.

```
[voicePromprtsettingsPicker selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

But first time I don't want to select any rows. I tried below code but not working.

```
[voicePromprtsettingsPicker selectRow:-1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

Thanks in advance for spending valuable time.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16976513/675170

Comment: That is different from my question. Please recheck it

Comment: we are here to help you. please check the duplicate question, it exactly describes the same.

Comment: Starting from ios 9, if we need a dropdown/picker field to be optional in a frorm entry for user, we are adviced to use accessoryview with cancel and ok buttons. That code to select a dummy row using -1 as index is no longer working


check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720606/add-buttons-to-uipickerview-swift-1-2

Answer (score 0):

You could always add a placeholder item into the picker view's source array.

For instance, your picker view's source array could look like this:

```
NSArray *voicePromptSettingsItems = @[@"Select a value", @"option 1", @"option 2", ...];
```

When the items load, the 0 index of the picker will be `Select a value`.

If you are requiring a user to select a value, before you continue, just make sure the selected index is not 0, and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you for answering question,Sorry I don't want to add any rows. Is there any other solution for this?